# Python requests.json() showing errors

Tags: python, python-requests

```
import requests
r = requests.get("http://link-short.rf.gd/codes/hello/package.json")
r.json()
```

The codes are showing me

```
File "c:\file.py", line 3, in <module>
    r.json()
  File "C:\Users\88019\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 910, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\88019\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\88019\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\88019\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

What is the problem and how can I solve that ?

Comment: Well, isn't it obvious? The response coming from that URL is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that JSON is not invalid. To be precise, the problem is not the link, but the file_2.txt file. So you have 2 solution: Check the file_2.text file and get a file that is correctly JSON, because this file is not. Or if you really can't get a JSON file, you can modify your code by inserting a request that applies to your file, because when you run your r (therefore a Requests) it makes assumptions about the encoding of the response based on the headers http. To change the encoding you can replace r.json () with r.text (), so like this:

```
import requests

r = requests.get ("http://link-short.rf.gd/codes/hello/file_2.txt")
r.text()
```

**UPDATE**

I noticed that you later changed the link in the question. Try these

```
import json
import requests

r = requests.get (http://link-short.rf.gd/codes/hello/package.json)
data = r.json()
```

or this, because it converts a string to access your JSON

```
import json
import requests

r = requests.get (http://link-short.rf.gd/codes/hello/package.json)
data = json.loads(r.text)
```

Comment: @Shahriyar Kabir Sami  I have updated the answer with two new solutions

Comment: @Shahriyar Kabir Sami If my answer, or that of other users, was the solution to your question, please accept the answer as Stackoverflow Help Center rules, thank you

Answer (score -1):

well `http://link-short.rf.gd/codes/hello/file_2.txt` does not supply a json.

So you could supply a link to a json file

Answer (score -1):

You cannot call r.json() if r is not a json file. Since your URL points to some file_2.txt, it is not in json() format and hence r.json() will not help you.

Consider using r.text() instead

Answer (score -2):

If you recently started using a **VPN** and hadn't run into this problem before, **turn off your VPN**.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).